# How can IIS10 (on Win 2019 Server) be configured with https so that you can use the server name in the URL

Tags: https, iis-10

I have an IIS10 server (y0185-web0181-s) and I want to use https so I can call like the following:

> https://y0185-web0181-s:44335/reviews

I'm currently getting that the site is not secure

[image]

Can IIS be configured so that a server name can be used in conjunction with https?

Maybe there some way to setup the certificate on IIS10 so it permits this type of usage?

Comment: "Not secure" is rather common, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Is this for internal development use?

Comment: Yes-exactly -- it's for internal site

Answer (score 0):

This warning means your domain has no trusted certificate when you enter https request to your website.So you should add a self certificate and then put it in Manage computer certificate module in your computer.

1. In your local machine, you should firstly  use powershell  and run as a administrator to create a self certificate which issure name is same as you domain , you could enter command as below(site1 is the name of your domain):

   `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.site1.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"`
2. Add https bindings to your site, make sure domain same as that in your self certificate.
3. In Manage computer  certificate module of your local machine ,use ctrl+ c copy the self certificate to trusted Root Certification tag.